# Jquery - get the same id in different divs

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<div class="myClass" id="TD_123">Test 1</div>   
<div class="myClass">Test 2</div>       
<div class="myClass">Test 3</div>       


$('.myClass').click(function() {

   var idValue = $(this).attr('id');
   alert(idValue);

 });
```

I don't know how getting the id value if I click on the second and the third div?

I can also use this implementation if it's easier to get the class beginning by "TD_" of the selected div:

```
<div class="myClass TD_123">Test 1</div>    
<div class="myClass TD_123">Test 2</div>        
<div class="myClass TD_123">Test 3</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: The second and third doesn't have an ID, and you can't get what's not there ?

Comment: Get the ID value? You have only specified an ID for the first div, what do you expect?

Comment: all elements must have unique ids, you cant use the second, in first the last 2 row dont have id's

Comment: Two class attribs are (as far as I know) invalid - you want `class="myClass TD_123"`

Comment: Also id's are unique... so you'll always get the first item with that id.

Comment: Read [Two HTML elements with same id attribute: How bad is it really?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use it like this :

```
<div class="myClass" id="TD_1">Test 1</div>   
<div class="myClass" id="TD_2">Test 2</div>       
<div class="myClass" id="TD_3">Test 3</div>       


$('.myClass').click(function() {

   var idValue = $(this).attr('id');
   alert(idValue);

 });
```

**EDIT :**

If you want have the SAME result on every div i guess you can try this :

```
<div class="myClass" data-title="TD_123">Test 1</div>   
<div class="myClass" data-title="TD_123">Test 2</div>       
<div class="myClass" data-title="TD_123">Test 3</div>       


$('.myClass').click(function() {

   var titleValue = $(this).attr('data-title');
   alert(titleValue);

 });
```

Comment: The value in the second attribut should be the same for my divs, that's why in the first code I chose to use Id in one of them.

Comment: I'd suggest a data attribute (perhaps `data-title`) instead of `title`, which creates a tooltip on mouseover